# Forever.js doesn't restart my Node.js / Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, forever

I'm using `forever.js` to make sure my Node.js / Express app runs without a break. However, sometimes it crashes and forever doesn't restart it.

I'm using

`forever start app.js`

to start the app

and it starts fine, works, and then at some point crashes and when I do

`forever list`

it doesn't list anything, so it simply doesn't restart...

I also tried running it with a log file, using

`forever start -l foreverlog.txt app.js`

and the log file is fine, but it doesn't show any info about the end of the process - e.g. the crash or error report, which I usually have if I run the `app.js` from my console directly.

Do you know how I could make forever restart the app or at least get the errors into the log?

Thank you!

Comment: Does `forever logs app.js` provide any details?

Comment: at the moment the app runs it provides the app's details, but i will test it next time the server goes down

Comment: when the app crashes (it just happened the first time since a week), `forever logs app.js` says it can't find app.js process so i guess it's not running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forever splits the log

```
-l  LOGFILE      Logs the forever output to LOGFILE
-o  OUTFILE      Logs stdout from child script to OUTFILE
-e  ERRFILE      Logs stderr from child script to ERRFILE
```

Even if you didn't specify the -e file it should be somewhere. Users/{UserName}/.forever on windows.

You should check the ERRFILE. Maybe that will bring some light to why the process failed.

Comment: Yes I found it but there's no errors there and no abnormal behavior. It simply stops with a page loading with 200 code so it seems normal. I'm thinking: maybe it's not my app but the whole node.js crashing? Is it possible? Would that mean that forever cannot restart the app for that reason?

Comment: I believe you are checking the wrong log file, the 200OK lines are written in the -o (OUTFILE). You should identify the -e (ERRFILE) or specify it the next time you run.

Comment: Thank you! It's true, I was checking the wrong file.

Comment: It's strange because the app crashed again and there was no error log - only the main one which simply breaks off in the midst of loading a page... Could the problem be with forever itself?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use spinSleepTime:

```
forever --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 -w -l *.log -e *.log --port 1234 app.js
```

--minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms

--spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms

Comment: WORKS - it helps to restart auto.

Answer (score -4):

Try killing the process manually by searching for the process with

```
ps axl | grep node
```

then

```
kill 24597
```

replace 24597 with your process number. Then reboot forever again.

http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever/